# How to sort files in a directory based on the index number of the file?

Tags: files, sort

I have files like :

```
4-some file.mp4
1-another file.mp4
3-one more file.mp4
2-got another file.mp4
```

and so on.

Using the command line to play the files in vlc using `vlc *` plays them in unsorted order.

So I tried to play the files using vlc "`vlc < <(ls * | sort -V)`" does not work.

Trying to change the timestamp of the files using
`for i in "$(ls [!R]* | sort -V)"; do touch "$i";sleep 1; done` is not working because `"$(ls [!R]* | sort -V)"` represents the complete list of files as one argument but I cannot remove the double quotes since files have spaces in their names.

Comment: is that the actual name of the file `4 - some file.mp4` Like with space in it?

Comment: yes the actual names of the files is like `235-Learning Objectives.mp4` ,  `232-Exercise 24.mp4` i have named them like this

Comment: The number of digits before the `-` differs?

Comment: yes it goes from 1 to 420

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
find . -name "*mp4" -print0 | sort -Vz | xargs -0 vlc
```

Comment: Why not `-n` for `sort`? This should also fix the problems with a differing amounts of digits.

Comment: @phk Try it with n.

Comment: @123 It works for me.

Comment: @phk no, the `-n` won't work. The `-V` seems to be doing something clever. To use `-n`, you would need to define the field to sort on. For example: `find . -name '*mp4' -printf '%f\0' |  sort  -t'-' -k 1.1n,1.3 -z`. If it works for you, try it again with a file name like `100-foo.mp4`. Or even `11-foo`.

Comment: I think the path name (`./`) in the beginning if `find` output is what confuses `sort -n`. It seems to work if you tell it to skip the first letters: `find . -name "*.mp4" -print0 | sort -z -k 1.3n | xargs -0 echo`. Also plain simple `ls -U | sort -n` works.

Answer (score 1):

GNU ls also has `-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text`, like `sort -V`.

The spaces in the filename can be dealt with by removing the space from `$IFS`, (assuming you don't have newlines in file names):

```
$ IFS=$'\n' 
$ for x in $(ls -v) ; do echo "> $x" ; done
> 1-aa aa
> 2-cc cc
> 10-bb bb
> 21-dd dd
$ vlc $(ls -v)
```

(If you do that interactively, `IFS` will remain modified afterwards.)

For more information about `IFS`, see [David Wheeler's writings about special characters in file names](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html#ifs)